# Rails 3 - Periodic Refresh of DIV

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I am trying to refresh the contents of a div using AJAX/Unobtrusive JavaScript/JQuery.

This is easy to do if I make a "refresh" link and give it a data-remote attribute.

However, I would like to refresh every 2 seconds using the setInterval function rather than using a link.

This code should demonstrate what I'm trying to do.  It does not work when put in application.js because the ERB is not evaluated, but hopefully it will explain my goal.

```
  setInterval(function(){
    $("#scuttlebutt").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'scuttlebutt') %>");
  },2000);
```

What would be a proper way to do this in Rails 3??

(I am working with Rails 3.2.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up putting code in application.js that would:

- Check if the div exists
- Make a timer using setInterval
- Request a js script from Rails at the current URL which would lead to the evaluating of a js.erb view file.  When this file was run it would update my div.

Behold...

assets/javascripts/application.js

```
$(function() {

  if ($('#scuttlebutt').length) {
    setInterval(function(){
      $.getScript(window.location.pathname, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        console.log('Load was performed.');
      });
    },2000);
  }

});
```

views/tickets/show.js.erb

```
$("#scuttlebutt").html(" <%= escape_javascript(render 'scuttlebutt') %>" );
```

Comment: found someone doing something similar here http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=48076

Comment: found this railscast very helpful as well http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I see what you are trying to do.  I have done this before, and I found a simple way of doing it.

You want to still have the button that calls your remote method in a controller that executes some javascript back at the browser to refresh that DIV.  I know, I know, you don't want to have it, but here me out.  I have one on my page, but I hid it way off to the side so that no one can ever find it, link this:

```
:id => "refresh_button", :style => "position: absolute; left: -9999px" // Rails ERB notation
```

Then, I added this to that same file, which I presume is a .html.erb file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doSomething() {
    $('#refresh-button').click();
  }

  setInterval('doSomething()',2000);
</script>
```

This will press the button every 2 seconds, calling your remote function as if some is clicking that button every two seconds.  It isn't the cleanest way of doing this, I know, but it works great in a pinch until you can get something more robust working for you.  Though you could technically use this.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Selah You are welcome.  Glad that I could help you out and answer your question correctly.  I works very well for me on the site I had to implement it on.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485856/json-rails-parse-error-in-javascirpt).

It states that .js files are not parsed like .erb files. They are passed as-is.

Comment: I realize that.  The code example is just to demonstrate what I am trying to do.