# Rails auto clicking a button to refresh div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm new to programming and teaching myself Rails as I build an app.

I have a page with a list of jobs. Each job is rendered via a job partial which has a div which renders a status partial via a "Update Status" button with ajax.
The button works as expected and refreshes each job's status when clicked.

I am now trying to make the status div auto-refresh every x seconds.
After trying different methods, I've implemented a javascript which simply periodically refreshes the button (which I can later hide if I want). It was suggested here by @de_an777: [Rails 3 - Periodic Refresh of DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022627/rails-3-periodic-refresh-of-div).

This seems to almost work for me.
The problem is that it doesn't refresh ALL jobs in the list. So if I have 2 jobs in the list, I see two refresh operations happening in the server log, but both of them refresh only the first job.
When inspecting the job id for each button element in the browser inspector, they all seem to have the correct id via job[:id].

I've been struggling with this for days, changing my routes and methods but cannot make it work. Hoping that someone can direct me in the right way...

**Jobs_controller.rb:**

```
 def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
        #some updating logic
        respond_to do |format|          
            format.js 
        end
  end
```

**index.html.erb:**

```
<div class="row">
    <aside class="col-md-4">
        <section class="user_info">
            <h1>Job List</h1>
        </section>
        <section class="job_form">
            <%= link_to "New Job", upload_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
        </section>
    </aside>
</div>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<%= render @jobs %>
```

**_job.html.rb:**

```
<span class="jobs">
    <p> Job ID: <%= job.id %></p>
    <p> Job Name: <%= job.name != "" ? job.name : "Untitled" %>
        <p> Source File: <%= job.source_file %></p>
        <% @job = job %>
        <div id="status_div_<%= @job.id %>">
            <%= render :partial => 'jobs/status', locals: {job: job} %>
        </div>
        <%= button_to("Update Status", jobs_update_path(id: job.id), remote: true, method: :patch, id: "refresh_#{job[:id]}") %>
    </span>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function doSomething() {
    $('#refresh_<%= job[:id] %>').click();
  }
  setInterval('doSomething()',10000);
</script>
```

**routes:**

```
  get 'new_job'     => 'jobs#new'
  get 'upload'      => 'jobs#upload'
  patch "jobs/update", to: "jobs#update"
  resources :jobs
```

**update.js.erb:**

```
$('#status_div_<%= @job.id %>').html("<%= j render :partial => 'status', object: @job, as: :job %>");
```

**_status.html.erb:**

```
<p> Status: <%= job[:status] %></p>
```

Comment: Don't struggle. Open up Browser Console and tell what you see?

Comment: Why are you using `$('#refresh_<%= job[:id] %>').click();`, why is it not `$('#refresh_<%= job.id %>').click();`?

Comment: if you wanna refresh all your jobs, just refresh partial as collection of your job, than all your object will refresh

Comment: @PraveenKumar: I see POST http://localhost:5000/jobs/update repeating itself (twice every 10 sec.)

Comment: @hattenn: I actually used job.id originally but then thought it might need the id as key. It makes no difference to the result.

Comment: @OlegSobchuk: I tried to use :collection in the route but couldn't make it work. Would you care to elaborate how exactly to do it?

Comment: @baerlein Click on that and see what mistake is there inside.

Comment: in view `<%= render partial: 'status', collection: @jobs %>` and same update it `$('#status_div_<%= @job.id %>').html("j <%= j render partial: 'status', collection: @jobs %>");`

Comment: @PraveenKumar: it doesn't look like a mistake. The method is marked with a green circle and 200POST. The Request URL is http://localhost:5000/jobs/update?id=302 . This is the ID of the first job which is repeated.

Comment: @baerlein Ah... I mistook it to be `500` Error. `:P`

Comment: @OlegSobchuk: tried it, same result. The same ID is being called twice.