# JSON returns 'Null' error... @object.to_json wrong place?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

### -Update-

found answer here: [json, rails, parse error in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485856/json-rails-parse-error-in-javascript)

also, see iltempo's answer below (thanks iltempo)

**JSON / GOOGLE MAPS**

**PlacesController, index respond_to block**

```
    format.json { render json: @places }
```

**places.js.erb (/assets)**

```
    var markersArray = <%= @places.to_json %>;
    addMarkerArray(markersArray);

    function addMarkerArray(markersArray) {
        for(var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
            var lt = markersArray[i].latitude;
            var lg = markersArray[i].longitude;
            ...
            ...
        }
    )
```

**Firebug Error**

```
    TypeError: markersArray is null 
    " for(var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) { "
```

Comment: can you post your full PlacesController?

Comment: Brad, thanks for trying to help but finally found stack question that answered it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485856/json-rails-parse-error-in-javascript  thanks again

Comment: Right on - I had overlooked the /assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to access the ERB template variable `@places` in a Javascript file placed in `assets/`. Instead call the function `addMarkerArray()` with the return value of the AJAX call you do to get the places data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Finally found a similar stack question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485856/json-rails-parse-error-in-javascript